# What might reasons be of having a Content Security Policy error when a CSP is not even specified?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, http-headers, content-security-policy

My web application is failing to load the static resources from a DigitalOcean Space, by throwing the following error in the browser console:

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://somespace.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/css/mystyle.css (“style-src”).
```

I went through some reading regarding CSP, and on [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP/Errors/CSPViolation#what_went_wrong) I found the following statement:

> This warning message means that due to the existence of a particular CSP directive, a resource wasn't loaded.

However, I have not provided any particular CSP directive. I am also providing a short snippet on how I am including the CSS file on my HTML document:

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://somespace.digitaloceanspaces.com/static/css/mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
</head>
```

Might there be another reason why this error is being thrown? What would be a workaround or at least a way to debug this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to firstly check the response headers you are receiving. The Content-Security-Policy should be defined there. This header contains the configurations. You can learn more about them here: https://content-security-policy.com/

Then, you need to determine where this header is being added. In my case, it was being added through an old NGINX configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error message with neither a document-level CSP nor one in my response headers. It seems like (at least on my Firefox) when the [NoScript](https://noscript.net/) browser addon blocks a script, it shows up as a CSP error in the developer console. Enabling scripts for the page in question resolved the issue.